Should I report a review I suspect to be AI-generated?
We've recently received reviews for a paper submitted to a top (STEM) journal in my field. Most reviews were helpful, but one was particularly sloppy, heavily misunderstanding our paper and making false and bizarre claims about its contents. Based on this particular review’s format and content, I heavily suspect it was written by feeding our paper to ChatGPT and making minimal edits, but I have no proof of this. The review also penalizes our paper for reasons the journal guidelines explicitly say are not acceptable.
The overall decision was revise and resubmit. I have no problem with the decision, but I am concerned about receiving this kind of review again post-revisions. I wanted to ask if it is worth flagging this particular review to the editor ahead of time, perhaps asking for a different reviewer, or if the review should be ordinarily addressed like one usually addresses reviews during revisions. I feel like a journal of this caliber might want to be aware of such reviews, but I am wary of making the claim that it was written by ChatGPT without proof, as this might be rather damaging/unfair to the reviewer.
I also wanted to ask if anyone has experience with possibly machine-generated reviews for their papers, and what they've done about it.

It sounds like hallucination if it is chatgpt. Do you feel you could challenge the quality of the review on its own due to bizarre claims (assuming it was written by a human)? When challenging it on that merit, you could suggest it was written by chatgpt?

The review's claims are in some parts easily challenged (they are plainly false), and in other cases unintelligible (as in, I could not find an interpretation that makes sense--it reads like a ChatGPT-esque hallucination). The unintelligible stuff is very hard to address because it "reads" like it makes sense, but doesn't if you are familiar with the paper. I can address this in revisions, but I am wary of my "rebuttal" coming off as overly aggressive/negative (I don't think they'll take this kindly) and I am wary of receiving the same type of ChatGPT-esque review in response.

Have you tried feeding your paper into ChatGPT yourself, to see whether it agrees with the suspect review? That might corroborate your suspicions.

@SimonCrase each run is seeded differently so in practice chatgpt won't tell you the same thing twice.


I feel like a journal of this caliber might want to be aware of such reviews, but I am wary of making the claim that it was written by ChatGPT without proof, as this might be rather damaging/unfair to the reviewer.

You don’t need to make a claim. You can just point out that the review feels machine-generated to you and list the major reasons why you think so. It is totally fine to report reasonably substantiated suspicions without rock-solid proof. The journal hopefully has more experience and resources to check whether a review was machine-generated, and they need to independently check any accusations made against reviewers anyway. If they blindly act on your hunch, this would be their fault, not yours.
I would even go further and argue that given sufficiently good (although not compelling) evidence, it’s your duty to report it. Such a reviewer could already have done considerable damage or do so in the future.

I wanted to ask if it is worth flagging this particular review to the editor ahead of time, perhaps asking for a different reviewer, or if the review should be ordinarily addressed like one usually addresses reviews during revisions.

I cannot say how bad this particular review is, but addressing a bogus review can be a major waste of time. Also, investigating your suspicion will take some time, which may delay the process if it’s only done upon resubmission.
I would therefore contact the journal immediately in hope that the review is voided. I don’t see a benefit of explicitly asking for a different reviewer though. It is up to the journal how to react to this.

I wouldn't expect that the journal would care about the generated review.
The main choice would be to the specific editor

@KY: Suppose a journal makes a bad decision based on an obviously AI-generated review, e.g., rejecting a decent paper. Suppose the authors go public about this and it gets verified. That would considerably harm the journal’s reputation. So, yes, I am quite confident they will care.

@KY In addition to the very applicable comment by Wrzlprmft, the whole purpose of peer review is to allow scientists to check the work of other scientists.  A generated review subverts that purpose.

@BobBrown I don't think this follows logically. If models were smart enough (yes, they aren't... yet), one could argue it would be irresponsible of reviewers not to discuss a paper with a model, and there could then be cases where an auto-generated review resulting from that discussion would suffice to justify a reject decision (or maybe even an accept decision). This would be similar to how everyone who is serious about analysing a chess game uses engines, and often engine output is sufficient to evaluate a particular move to everyone's satisfaction.

The best approach may be to challenge the review directly with the editor on grounds of quality, prior to your revision, and assuming the review was written by a human. During that challenge you can focus on the false/bizarre claims and the issues that the review raises that the journal guidelines say should not be reasons for penalisation. During this you can raise the idea of it being chatgpt, but it sounds like the review is weak enough to challenge by itself.
I'll change the framing question, to point out that there is nothing automatically wrong with a chatgpt review, just as there would be nothing automatically wrong with a monkey's review. So long as its checked by a someone who read and understood the paper to make sure its correct and complete and would be willing to put their name to it. The method the text is produced, human/AI/monkey, could be treated as a black box, a brilliant and insightful review created by chatgpt would still brilliant and insightful. So the focus of the challenge should be on why the review is poor and should be ignored rather than that you suspect it was written by chatgpt (or written by a monkey).
Of course, submitting a sub-par AI generated review is insulting since it is a waste of everyone's time. It would also probably be quicker for a reviewer to write it themselves rather than try to tweak current AIs to get a meaningful review from them. This may not be the case in the future, but current AIs tend to write generic stuff and lack any understanding of the kinds of topics that are on the cutting edge, such as research.

I'll point out that there is nothing necessarily wrong with a chatgpt review, so long as its checked by a knowledgeable reviewer to make sure its correct and complete. – This seems to ignore the fact that the major time sink of a review is reading and understanding the manuscript, which the reviewer checking a machine-generated review would have to do anyway. Also, I doubt that genAI can read plots or detect more than very superficial problems with a manuscript, etc. So the potential time save seems to be negligible. (Mind that this is different for genAI polishing the language of a review.)

@Wrzlprmft, I 100% agree with this, the point I was trying to make is that if it was written by chatgpt and verified by someone who took the time to read and understand the paper who then verified that chatgpt had (somehow) managed to write a valid review then there is nothing wrong with it. But the chances chatgpt actually does do this is negligible at its current level of technology. So its better to target the review as if it was written by a human, then suggest at the end that you suspect chatgpt was used, which wasted everyone's time. I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.

LLM output is harder to verify than random output, because it's specifically optimized to be superficially reasonable sounding, but without regard for actual correctness, since correctness is too hard to quantify during training. In other words, it's much more likely for even an expert to falsely conclude LLM output is correct than random output.

@Vaelus LLM output is harder to reject as invalid, but not necessarily easier to accept as valid, than random output. All the superficially reasonable text that LLMs generate are also generated by uniformally random output, but just much much slower. The point I'm making is that when challenging AI reviews, its likely that the review will not be correlated with journal policy and paper content, just as a terrible human review would be. In theory an AI may come up with the perfect review (or a reviewer may guide the AI to such a review), but this is unlikely.

What’s the point of the second and third paragraph? We all seem to agree that the probability of a good machine-generated review is negligible. However, a reviewer submitting machine-generated reviews is a big problem as it may not be spotted every time – even though the reviews are bad every time. (For example, suppose the machine generates a positive review consisting mainly of a summary of the manuscript and stuff so minor even an AI can find it.) Ignoring that a review is very likely machine-generated and addressing only its text is borderline irresponsible (and a waste of time).

The entire point of a review is to be the opinion of an expert in the field, not the opinion of a monkey, robot etc. that the expert just happens to agree with. It very much does matter that the expert writes the review rather than merely signing off on it.

Note that the US National Institutes of Health prohibits the use of AI in peer review. Beyond what has been mentioned here, theft of unpublished confidential information is also a concern.
